# ¿"han [...] para que haya"... es correcto?

Tags: subjuntivo

Vivo en Argentina y se me presentó el siguiente ejemplo:

> Se le han dado clases de ciudadanía para que haya amado al país.

¿Es correcto pensar que está mal por el hecho de que los dos verbos ocurren en el mismo tiempo (pretérito)?

¿Seria mejor la siguiente versión o está siquiera permitida?

> Se le han dado clases de ciudadanía para que ame al país.

Comment: La última me parece correcta. Sin embargo, no creo que sea la "versión correcta" de lo que quiere expresar la primera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes de opciones en este caso:

- **para que ama<sup>ra</sup>/<sub>se</sub>**
  Úsase el *pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo* para indicar que
  las clases no se las seguirán dando (ya tomó todas las clases)
- **para que ame**
  Empléase el *presente del subjuntivo* para mantener abierta la posibilidad de que haya más clases en el futuro (todavía está tomando las clases)

No creo que sea posible usar los tiempos compuestos después de *para que*, ya que usamos *para que* para hablar de acciones venideras o coetáneas.  Es por eso que tampoco sería común (si no completamente incorrecto) decir algo del tipo *Trabajo para que fuese …*, ya que es imposible en el presente ejercer influencia –por medio de la acción de trabajar– sobre el pasado.

Comment: Sería aplicable, vos ultimo ejemplo en ese situacíon?

*Me peleé con mi novia y todavía está enojado. Es un problema.* - Se podría decir:  *Trabajo para que fuese un problema. (pero no resulta)*? - como - *Trabajo para que hubiere sido un problema (aunque no creo que resultare)*

Comment: I don't know if that makes sense at all, i'm trying to learn spanish, but the subjunctive is confusing me.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 I'm afraid I don't follow. What are you trying to say in English (more that future subjunctive has very limited uses in modern Spanish and won't be used with *para que* — even in a language like Portuguese that preserves it)